# need to bind the values to gridview textbox column in telerik for winform

Tags: .net

i need to bind values from db to gridview textbox column, but i noticed there is no way to bind that in griview textboxcolumn in telerik winform, if there is any solution for that will appreciate
Thanks in advance
Ashok.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of examples [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-databinding-radgridview.html). Anyways, it seems to be the same as with the Windows Forms DataGridView.

Here's one example, taken from the link.

```
// Sample class
    public class MyObject
    {
        public MyObject(int myInt, string myString)
        {
            _myInt = myInt;
            _myString = myString;
        }
        private int _myInt;
        public int MyInt
        {
            get { return _myInt; }
            set { _myInt = value; }
        }
        private string _myString;
        public string MyString
        {
            get { return _myString; }
            set { _myString = value; }
        }
    }


// Binding to a Generic BindingList of Sample class
private BindingList<MyObject> myList;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myList = new BindingList<MyObject>();
    myList.Add(new MyObject(1, "Outdoor"));
    myList.Add(new MyObject(2, "Hardware"));
    myList.Add(new MyObject(3, "Tools"));
    myList.Add(new MyObject(4, "Books"));
    myList.Add(new MyObject(5, "Appliances"));
    myList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
    myList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(myList_ListChanged);
    radGridView1.DataSource = myList;
}
void myList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ListChangedType.ToString() + ": at index: " + e.NewIndex.ToString() + ", \"" + myList[e.NewIndex].MyString + "\"");
}
private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myList.Add(new MyObject(6, "Plants"));
}
```

Comment: Hi Jhenriquez, Thanks for ur reply.. seems u answered for listbox, but  am asking about how to bind a value in gridview textbox column in win app..

Comment: @user769880, I guess I did not understand the question fully. Could you please provide a little more detail of what you're trying to achieve.